# How to add users to the search results?

Tags: users, search, forloop

I'm trying to display three different sets of data in search results. The first two, News and Services I can easily concatenate by the following:

```
{% set searchSections =  craft.entries.section(['service', 'newsOpinion']) %}
{% for entry in searchSections.search(query).order('score').limit(52).find()  %}
```

This way the results display both sections limited and ordered via score no matter what section they are in.

Ideally I want to add a third array to searchSections of users.

```
{% set allStaff = craft.users.group('staff') %}
{% for user in allStaff.search(query).order('score').limit(52).find() %}
```

However users aren't a section and merging the three arrays doesn't work. Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult, if not impossible, to do accurately in Craft 2.4.

In the upcoming [Craft 2.5](http://buildwithcraft.com/beta), the actual search score is being returned in the results, so you'd be able to take the two arrays, merge and sort them via their score into one result-set.